# redux, versioning preloadedState?

Tags: redux

http://redux.js.org/docs/api/createStore.html

> [preloadedState] (any): The initial state. You may optionally specify
> it to hydrate the state from the server in universal apps, or to
> restore a previously serialized user session.

I can successfully initialize store with the preloadedState parameter.

However there are times I need to change the structure of the state.

As an example, I initially had

```js
{
  totalCount: 3,
  usedCount: 1
}
```

now I want to change it to

```js
{ 
  totalCount: 3,
  unusedCount: 2
}
```

Then stored state in the first structure won't be valid now.
At least I want to discard old state and start afresh from the new initialState.

I'm storing state in the server and using it as the preloadedState param.
Is there a way to discard the server stored state when state structure changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I''m sharing my solution.
I created HOC reducer (http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ReusingReducerLogic.html)

```js
 export function versionedReducer(reducerFunction) {

   return (state, action) => {

     const isInitializationCall = state === undefined

     if (isInitializationCall) {
       return state
     }

     const { version } = reducerFunction(undefined, {type: undefined})
     if (!version) {
       throw "should versioned"
     }
     const shouldAcceptPreloadedState = state.version && state.version >= version

     if (!shouldAcceptPreloadedState) {
       state = undefined
     }

     return reducerFunction(state, action)

   }
 }
```